# How to 'continue' from within ForEach<T> WorkFlow activity?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

At the moment I'm capturing any relevant exceptions, then using an If activity to decide whether to continue processing or not. In non workflow code I'd just **continue** to the next item.

Is there a Workflow equivalent to **continue**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither **continue**, nor **break** for that matter, are natively implemented inside WF. You can easily implement it with a custom NativeActivity.

Check [this link](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=21459) for the official samples. At *WF\Basic\Built-InActivities\EmulatingBreakInWhile* folder you've an example on how to emulate **break** behaviour. Same thing can be done to **continue**.